# Ensure registered users can publish nodes only after paying some money

Tags: 8, payment-gateways

Is there a way to charge registered users who publish a node in a Drupal 8 site?

If I'm not wrong, the pricing process should be easier as Web services are now part of the core in Drupal 8.

Pricing should be through Paypal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-existing solutions ( [Commerce Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout),   [UC Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_node_checkout), [Pay-per-node](https://www.drupal.org/project/paypernode)) for this problem haven't been ported into D8.

If one of the pre-existing solutions covers your use case well, you could help port it to D8 (Commerce 2.x is likely to have a stable release this year). Otherwise, you're looking at some sort of custom solution involving involving modifying the node form workflow and PayPal integration.